# DownGrade ASP Core Docker supported Project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-docker-extensions

I Created a ASP CORE 1.1 project with docker support. it runs.

Now when i downgrade it to asp core 1.0 and run the docker mode i got

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use
>   Microsoft.NETCoreapp 1.0.0 or newer [..]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When downgrading the solution the docker file doesn't get updated.

Update in docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
```

to

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0
```

Comment: Thats the side effects of using tools/ui you never know what to change best is to know and own the dockerfile too! :+1: for answering it!